# Improperly stored instance state in Action Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, action-filter

I just upgraded my project from ASP.NET MVC1.0 to ASP.NET MVC4.0

One thing that realy frightens me is the the following sentence on the upgrade documentation to MVC3.0

> In previous versions of ASP.NET MVC, action filters are create per
>   request except in a few cases.  This behavior was never a guaranteed
>   behavior but merely an implementation detail and the contract for
>   filters was to consider them stateless.  In ASP.NET MVC 3, filters are
>   cached more aggressively.  Therefore, any custom action filters which
>   improperly store instance state might be broken.

I think there is no easy way to test for errors caused by improperly stored instance state .
If I have an issue am pretty confident that I will only find it in production.

What does improperly stored instance state realy mean here?

I have this code:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel()
   filterContext.ActionParameters["model"] = productModel;
}
```

Is this a sample of improperly stored instance state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your code snippet is fine. Improperly stored state would be some class level properties eg:

```
public class StatefulActionFilter : ActionFilter
{
  private readonly IPrincipal currentPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    ...
    // Using currentPrincipal here would be bad, since it may refer to the principal of a previous request.
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: And how to avoid them? I want to keep some simple options for the filter, there is a global registration with default value for every instance, and some controllers have their own attributes with other values. Current approach of using instance-level properties loses the global values.

Comment: Hi @Akbari, I'm not sure I understand your comment - could you elaborate? Or if it's another related, but tangential query, please ask another question on SO and link to it here? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Rich, I actually asked the question at here [https://stackoverflow.com/q/47666835/3967440]. Thanks for your attention.